# Python Combine Elements in one List With All Elements in Another

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

Given the following lists:

```
a = ['a','b']
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

I'd like to produce this:

```
c = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','b4']
```

So I basically want to join every element of b to each element in a.

I'd like an approach similar to this:

```
[x+str(y) for x in a and y in b]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `c = [x+str(y) for x in a and y in b]` is the solution which you have included in your question, what are you actually asking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = ['a','b']
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = [x+str(y) for x in a for y in b]
print(c)
```

Comment: +0.5 for your answer, and +0.5 for your username.

Comment: ditto, @elethan's comment :P

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate twice within the *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> a = ['a','b']
>>> b = [1,2,3,4]

>>> [i+str(j) for i in a for j in b]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
```

Comment: Haha, looks like you are the winner ;)

Comment: @HillaryClintonEmailRemover BTW I liked your name :D :D

Answer (score 2):

You can also mix list comprehension with generation of combinations.
Itertools module is a good way how to work with combinations.

```
import itertools
c = [x + str(y) for x, y in itertools.product(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replacing the `and` in your example with a `for` to add an extra loop:

```
[x + str(y) for x in a for y in b]
```

This will loop through both lists in a single [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

```
[str(a1) + str(b1) for a1 in a for b1 in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived too late to this question, but here are my two cents for doing this on python 3.6+

```
[f'{a_item}{b_item}' for a_item in a for b_item in b]
```