# Looping Through two lists of lists

Tags: python, list

My problem is how combine two lists of lists so that b is repeated as many times as sublists in a:

Assuming: `a = [[0,0], [1,1]]` and `b = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]`,

Essentially, I want to create a new list to look like the following:

`c = [[0,0,2,3,4], [0,0,5,6,7],[0,0,7,8,9],[1,1,2,3,4], [1,1,5,6,7],[1,1,7,8,9]]`

I tried several approaches but they assumed a list in a and b:
`a = [0,1]; b = [2,5,7]; c = [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]`
which resulted in:

`c =  [(0, 2), (0, 5), (0, 7), (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 7)]`

but I need to generalise for a high number of sublists.
Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Combine Elements in one List With All Elements in Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191039/python-combine-elements-in-one-list-with-all-elements-in-another)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get every combination of elements from two (or more) iterables, `itertools.product` has got you.

```
from itertools import product

a = [[0,0], [1,1]]
b = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]

out = [list_a + list_b for (list_a, list_b) in product(a, b)]
print(out)
```

**Edit:** Changed the name for the sub-lists used in comprehension to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You just need nested for loops to create the new lists you want:

```py
a = [[0,0], [1,1]]
b = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]

c = []
for p in a:
    for item in b:
        c.append(p+item)

print(c)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 0):

This code using `NumPy` to combine two arrays, a and b, by repeating and aligning their elements. It then horizontally stacks the repeated arrays to produce the desired output.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
b = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]])
a_repeated = np.repeat(a, b.shape[0], axis=0)
b_repeated = np.tile(b, (a.shape[0], 1))
output = np.hstack((a_repeated, b_repeated))
print(output.tolist())
```

> Note : This code demonstrates advanced array manipulation techniques using `NumPy` for efficient data processing.